# Binding Command to Native Views in Xamarin.forms Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I have followed several tutorials on consuming native views in Xamarin.Forms, But I didn't succeed in Binding Command to From ViewModel to the Native View.

Here is the code for the custom Native control in android:

```
public class MyFAB : FloatingActionButton
{
    public Command Command { get; set; }

    public MyFAB (Context context) : base(context)
    {
        this.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_add_white_24dp);

        Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Command?.Execute(null);
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the Xaml Code:

```
<droidCustom:AddFAB x:Arguments="{x:Static formsDroid:Forms.Context}" UseCompatPadding="true" Command="{Binding AddCategoryCommand}"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,AutoSize,AutoSize" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
```

The View is shown properly, but the command is not fired, and when I debug, the Command is never assigned it is always null.
When I go through blog posts online, they say the command binding will not need any bindable property... but here I still get issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a simple `Command` property. To achieve this, you must create a `BindableProperty` instead.

Change the `Command`'s property declaration to this and it should work:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyFAB), null);
public ICommand Command
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
} 

// Adding support to command parameters
public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CommandParameter), typeof(object), typeof(MyFAB), null);
public object CommandParameter
{
    get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
}
```

And the `Click` handler:

```
Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Command?.Execute(CommandParameter);
    };
```

I hope it helps you. Take a look at the [official Microsoft docs about `BindablePropperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) to more detailed explanation

Comment: Thanks for you help but it didn't go, the GetValue and SetValue methods are not recognized since the Command is in a class which inherits from Floating action button and is not a BindableObject. According to the documentations, only BIndableObjects have Get and SetValue

Comment: You are absolutely right. I've missed it up. I'll try to figure out a way to make it work. Until there, you'll not be able to use bindings indeed.

Comment: What if we change the `MyFAB` inheritance from `FloatingActionButton` to `View`, expose the properties, events, and methods you need then set an instance of `FloatingActionButton` as the NativeControl to your custom view? Do you think it can fit for you?

Comment: It would work if I was on the shared project, but actually I'm on the Android side, trying to create a FAB, and Bind the command in the shared project. the view shows but teh command is the issue, online they say no Bindable property is needed but though I can bind the command.

Comment: _create a FAB, and Bind the command in the shared project_ <- Is that what I meant. I'll make some experiments with this. Can you share the tutorials you've based?

Comment: Here is the tutorial, thanks https://codemilltech.com/bindable-native-views-in-xaml-with-commands/